# Parse.com EmailAsUsername in SignUpViewController

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfloginviewcontroller

I just downloaded the latest Parse SDK for iOS (1.2.21) because the change log shows that the EmailAsUsername attribute has been fixed. However while it works for the PFLoginViewController it doesn't seem to work for PFSignUpViewController.

I subclassed both controllers and do the

```
    OPLoginViewController *logInViewController = [[OPLoginViewController alloc] init];
    logInViewController.delegate = self;
    logInViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword | PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsSignUpButton ;
    logInViewController.emailAsUsername = YES;
    // Customize the Sign Up View Controller
    OPSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[OPSignUpViewController alloc] init];
    signUpViewController.delegate = self;
    signUpViewController.fields = PFSignUpFieldsDefault | PFSignUpFieldsAdditional ;
    signUpViewController.emailAsUsername = YES;
```

It works like a charm for the loginViewController however the signUpViewController totally ignores the setting.

Can anyone confirm this behavior or tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you specify your subclass as a delegate.  I know you have `signUpViewController.delegate = self;` but in your .h of your subclass you should have `<PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>`

Comment: Yes I did `...UIViewController <PFLogInViewControllerDelegate, PFSignUpViewControllerDelegate>`. I suspect a bug in the SDK?!

Comment: Definitely not a bug in the sdk because I had the same issue.  Are are presenting the correct view controller?  That was an issue I was having.  I was setting up a view controller but presented the default parse one.

Comment: `OPSignUpViewController` should be your delegate.

Comment: Ok thanks - that did it. I didn't take into account that the signup controller was called from the custom login controller. Duh!

Comment: No problem  That gave me a ton of issues myself.